# How can I calculate the size of a circle which is circumscribing a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, material-design

I am attempting to recreate the Material Ripple Effect shown here: https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/examples

I created a button (an element with `height: 36px;` and `padding: 0 16px;` (with some text in there too) and implemented an algorithm to calculate the location of the ripple based on a user's click location, and another algorithm to find the smallest possible size for the ripple effect (the diagonal length of the rectangle. This measurement would be applied if the user were to click directly in the center of the button).

The location of the user's click is formatted as pixels from the left (PosX) and pixels from the top (PosY).

```
PosX: 27
PosY: 16
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to calculate the diameter of the circle when the user clicks in any given spot within the rectangle. For example, let's say we have a rectangle measuring 30px by 40px. If the user clicks directly in the center of the rectangle (`PosX: 15`, `PosY: 20`), the ripple that is created will have a height & width of 50px and will be in the center of the rectangle, covering the entire shape perfectly.

But what if the user clicks towards the left and up a little, for example? Let's say the user clicks on `PosX: 10`, `PosY: 12`. Finding the location of the ripple's center is fairly easy:

```
ripple.style.left = PosX - rippleSize / 2 + "px";
ripple.style.top = PosY - rippleSize / 2 + "px";
```

But **how do I find the rippleSize when the user clicks on `PosX: 10` and `PosY: 12`?**

I hope I included enough information in here. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Here is my work so far: https://codepen.io/BlackKnightNick/pen/abNmZbz

**EDIT:** I imagine it to look like some sort of radial gradient starting from the center that would determine the scale of the circle (with the minimum size, the user clicking in the very center, being `transform: scale(1)` and the maximum size, with the user clicking in one of the corners, being `transform: scale(2)`. Not sure if that helps at all, but I decided to add it just in case.

Comment: I've looked at the Material Ripple Effect, and it seems to me like the initial circle diameter is constant and depends solely on the rectangular size - not on the click position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jonathan mentioned in the comment this can be accomplished by setting a constant value for `rippleSize`. But this may not produce the required effect. Here is a simple approach :

```
let x = PosX, y = PosY, h = buttonHeight, w = buttonWidth;
let rippleSize = Math.sqrt( Math.max( x*x + y*y , x*x + (h-y)*(h-y),
                                  (x-w)*(x-w) + (h-y)*(h-y), (w-x)*(w-x) + h*h));
```

Here I simply calculate the distance from each corner and take the value which is the largest among them. This logic can easily be abstracted to a function if you want.

```
function distance(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
}

let rippleSize = Math.max(distance(0,0,x,y),distance(0,h,x,y),
                          distance(w,0,x,y),distance(w,h,x,y));
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the overall formula, to get the scale factor, you could do the following:

```
D = button diagonal length
C = distance from click to button center

scale = (((((D / 2) - C) / (D / 2)) - 1) * -1) + 1
```

Which will yield a result between `1` and `2`. You'll need to calculate the distance between the click and the center of the button, which should be a similar equation to how you're calculating the diagonal length of the button.

Alternatively, you could make the radius of your circle equal to the button's diagonal length, and then not have to worry about resizing it based on the click position.